# System.Security.XmlSyntaxException "Invalid syntax on line 6."

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, servicestack

I am using CryptUtils class at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/CryptUtils.cs. My public key size is 397 I am doing,

`CryptUtils.Encrypt(key, "data", RsaKeyLengths.Bit512);`

But I am getting,

`System.Security.XmlSyntaxException "Invalid syntax on line 6."`

Sample public key(just updated some chars),

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ9AMIIBCgKCAQEAoqB1N9kugk4UKYnbh0fcg3qYyYKP0m4B
MjWd05ReeAdj+7JRYDEKO6xthDdVSdRO1/2V+YtY8DnXWnxRaICwu8235s3imZCyqgYnomPWdY+F
K540oTz/zug+9wbrlzt/WQFUU4lPlQbzm/Gjw8XfaCozT0e3bnWQcD7rORCOyuJgwSGgREjTv1ss
pgEaKTMknii9vpGZLeAXwoeIYROhuT4IoIkPDhtY0/UZiCi6v7Ja2dmy53VlWIkcm3rcnSJdvpXr
OgiHvaNABHmeymNycNqd6WUaysBRheluQ86nq/2nZPW0gcvmYt5zbMMYX3yY/n2WtAKeNQBAEW1q
b0s6MwIDAQAB
```

Will I need to convert this into xml?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ServiceStack
{
    public enum RsaKeyLengths
    {

        Bit512 = 512,
        Bit1024 = 1024,
        Bit2048 = 2048,
        Bit4096 = 4096
    }

    public class RsaKeyPair
    {
        public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
        public string PublicKey { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Useful .NET Encryption Utils from:
    /// http://andrewlocatelliwoodcock.com/2011/08/01/implementing-rsa-asymmetric-public-private-key-encryption-in-c-encrypting-under-the-public-key/
    /// </summary>
    public static class CryptUtils
    {

        public static string Encrypt(this string data)
        {
            if (KeyPair != null)
                return Encrypt(KeyPair.PublicKey, data, Length);
            else throw new ArgumentNullException("No KeyPair given for encryption in CryptUtils");
        }

        public static string Decrypt(this string data)
        {
            if (KeyPair !=null)
                return Decrypt(KeyPair.PrivateKey, data, Length);
            else throw new ArgumentNullException("No KeyPair given for encryption in CryptUtils");
        }

        public static RsaKeyLengths Length;
        public static RsaKeyPair KeyPair;


        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt an arbitrary string of data under the supplied public key
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="publicKey">The public key to encrypt under</param>
        /// <param name="data">The data to encrypt</param>
        /// <param name="length">The bit length or strength of the public key: 1024, 2048 or 4096 bits. This must match the 
        /// value actually used to create the publicKey</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string Encrypt(string publicKey, string data, RsaKeyLengths length = RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048)
        {
            // full array of bytes to encrypt
            byte[] bytesToEncrypt;

            // worker byte array
            byte[] block;

            // encrypted bytes
            byte[] encryptedBytes;

            // length of bytesToEncrypt
            var dataLength = 0;

            // number of bytes in key                
            var keySize = 0;

            // maximum block length to encrypt          
            var maxLength = 0;

            // how many blocks must we encrypt to encrypt entire message?
            var iterations = 0;

            // the encrypted data
            var encryptedData = new StringBuilder();

            // instantiate the crypto provider with the correct key length
            var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider((int)length);

            // initialize the RSA object from the given public key
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publicKey);

            // convert data to byte array
            bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

            // get length of byte array
            dataLength = bytesToEncrypt.Length;

            // convert length of key from bits to bytes
            keySize = (int)length / 8;

            // .NET RSACryptoServiceProvider uses SHA1 Hash function
            // use this to work out the maximum length to encrypt per block
            maxLength = ((keySize - 2) - (2 * SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(bytesToEncrypt).Length));

            // how many blocks do we need to encrypt?
            iterations = dataLength / maxLength;

            // encrypt block by block
            for (int index = 0; index <= iterations; index++)
            {
                // is there more than one full block of data left to encrypt?
                if ((dataLength - maxLength * index) > maxLength)
                {
                    block = new byte[maxLength];
                }
                else
                {
                    block = new byte[dataLength - maxLength * index];
                }

                // copy the required number of bytes from the array of bytes to encrypt to our worker array
                Buffer.BlockCopy(bytesToEncrypt, maxLength * index, block, 0, block.Length);

                // encrypt the current worker array block of bytes
                encryptedBytes = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(block, true);

                // RSACryptoServiceProvider reverses the order of encrypted bytesToEncrypt after encryption and before decryption.
                // Undo this reversal for compatibility with other implementations
                Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);

                // convert to base 64 string
                encryptedData.Append(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes));
            }

            return encryptedData.ToString();
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string privateKey, string data, RsaKeyLengths length = RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048)
        {
            var dwKeySize = (int)length;
            // TODO: Add Proper Exception Handlers
            var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(dwKeySize);
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(privateKey);

            int base64BlockSize = ((dwKeySize / 8) % 3 != 0) ?
              (((dwKeySize / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4 : ((dwKeySize / 8) / 3) * 4;

            int iterations = data.Length / base64BlockSize;

            var arrayList = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(
                     data.Substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));
                // Be aware the RSACryptoServiceProvider reverses the order of 
                // encrypted bytes after encryption and before decryption.
                // If you do not require compatibility with Microsoft Cryptographic 
                // API (CAPI) and/or other vendors.
                // Comment out the next line and the corresponding one in the 
                // EncryptString function.
                Array.Reverse(encryptedBytes);
                arrayList.AddRange(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, true));
            }

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(arrayList.ToArray(typeof(byte)) as byte[]);
        }

        public static RsaKeyPair CreatePublicAndPrivateKeyPair(RsaKeyLengths length = RsaKeyLengths.Bit2048)
        {
            var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider((int)length);
            return new RsaKeyPair
            {
                PrivateKey = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true),
                PublicKey = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false),
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create Public and Private Key Pair based on settings already in static class.
        /// </summary>        
        /// <returns>RsaKeyPair</returns>
        public static RsaKeyPair CreatePublicAndPrivateKeyPair()
        {
            var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider((int)Length);            
            return new RsaKeyPair
            {
                PrivateKey = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(true),
                PublicKey = rsaProvider.ToXmlString(false),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there should be semicolon `(;)` after enum declaration `public enum RsaKeyLengths
    {

        Bit512 = 512,
        Bit1024 = 1024,
        Bit2048 = 2048,
        Bit4096 = 4096
    };`

Comment: @CodingDefined this code is compiled.

Comment: Your syntax error is an `XmlSyntaxException` there is nothing wrong with the code. It's your key file format that is badly formed. The key should be XML, and there is an issue with it on line 6.

Comment: Scott I have a key provided by some company. The key length is 397. I need to use RSA to encrypt the string.

Comment: @Scott, I updated the question to include a sample updated RSA public key. will i need to convert this into xml?

Comment: Wow, that library is doing ECB on RSA-OAEP??? Please, whoever designed this, read http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2009/7/22/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem . Stop designing anything related to cryptography until you understand them.

Comment: @Gilles, ServiceStack is very popular framework. You are saying they are doing this wrong? Also what should I do? I just need to encrypt string using RSA using the sample key given above. You have any sample code. Please help me I am very much upset.

Comment: @user960567 I think ServiceStack is being misused in this API, but I don't know where ServiceStack stops and where whatever API you're implementing starts.

Comment: @Giles any sample code. Note CryptUtils class is from ServiceStack and api is third part bank api. Please provide me sample code and where I can read more about cryptogrpahy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it using,

```
var key = await GetPublicKey();
            var keyXml = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + key + "</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
EncrptedValue = CryptUtils.Encrypt(keyXml, "amount=1&currency=aed", RsaKeyLengths.Bit1024);
```

Comment: @user960567 How did you go about decrypting the private key using the `CryptUtils.Decrypt()` method? Did you encase the private key in XML and pass the same key size as in `Encrypt()`?

Answer (score 0):

Input of **FromXmlString**  is a public key And should be

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus> ***KEYString*** </Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```